# Encapsulating a web page inside a C#/XAML Metro app

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In the msdn docs it says in an HTML/CSS/JS Metro app an iFrame can be added to the page and website content can be loaded from a 'web context'

I would prefer to work in C#/XAML for this Metro app and I would just like it to encapsulate a website.

What is the correct method for displaying a website within a XAML page? Is there an equivalent of an iFrame in XAML? Can it be made full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WebView class to display HTML content in a XAML app.

Comment: Thanks Filip! Do you know what rendering engine it uses? Will the HTML content behave the same as in a browser?

Comment: Of course it should use the same rendering engine as IE. Word of warning though - you might see some airspace issues if you want to display anything over the web content. Need to swap out the WebView for WebViewBrush when displaying anything on top of the web content and swap it back when done to enable interaction with the web content.